# What is the URL for sending GET request to the database on your machine?

Tags: jquery, ajax, get

I'm using ajax to send a GET request to retrieve the info from my database on my machine, and currently it's giving me an error of the following:

'Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:3000/api/groceries' from origin 'http://127.0.0.1:5501' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.'

This is the ajax request i'm sending for the GET request in my App component:

```
  getGroceries () {
    $.ajax({
      method: 'GET',
      url: 'http://localhost:3000/api/groceries',
      success: (groceries) => this.setState({
        groceries: groceries
      }),
      error: error => console.log(error)
    })
  }
```

This is the server that i've set up on my machine:

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const port = 3000
const groceryController = require('./Controller/controllerGrocery.js')

app.get('/api/grocery', (req, res) => {
  groceryController.getGrocery(req, res)
})

app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: true}));

app.post('/api/grocery', (req, res) => {
  groceryController.addGrocery(req, res)
})

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Example app listening at http://localhost:${port}`)
})
```

What is the correct URL to use to retrieve info for the GET request in ajax? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There may not be a problem with URL but CORS.

You need to enable CORS (Cross-Origin Resource Sharing).

You can find further information about CORS here:
[https://owasp.org/www-community/attacks/CORS_OriginHeaderScrutiny#:~:text=Introduction,domain%20than%20is%20source%20domain](https://owasp.org/www-community/attacks/CORS_OriginHeaderScrutiny#:%7E:text=Introduction,domain%20than%20is%20source%20domain).

What you need to do is to enable CORS on your server.

Add cors package on your project with:

npm install cors
or
yarn add cors

And use it on the server.js (or main backend .js file):

```js
const cors = require("cors");

app.use(cors());
```